# MKmapview - CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: xcode, mkmapview

I have an array NSMutableArray where I save an MKuserlocation type - locationArray.
anyway now I want to get the data from this array and save it to an array from type CLLocationCoordinate2D.
but since everything I save in locationArray is from id type how can I get the coordinates from this and save it to the second array?

```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D* coordRec = malloc(pathLength * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    for(id object in locationArray){
        for (int i = 0; i < pathLength; i++)
            ?????
```

I dont know if this even possible!

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this `coordRec` array? For `MKPolyline`?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a c-style array of CLLocationCoordinate2D objects?

Here you go:

```
NSArray* userLocations; // contains your MKUserLocation objects...

CLLocationCoordinate2D* coordinates = malloc( userLocations.count * sizeof( CLLocationCoordinate2D) );

for ( int i = 0 ; i < userLocations.count ; i++ )
{
    coordinates[i] = [[[userLocations objectAtIndex: i] location] coordinate];
}
```

Comment: He might need for `MKPolyLine` which mystifyingly takes a c-style array, not a `NSArray`. Might it be better to define `coordinates` as `CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[userLocations.count];`, which accomplishes the same thing, but you don't have to worry about forgetting/mismatched `free()`? Clearly if ivar, you have to go `malloc` approach, but if local array, the c-style array might be safer.

Comment: @Rob - I didn't realize this was now legal in C.  It used to be the size of an array declared on the stack had to be a compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to create a `NSObject` subclass and define a single property, a `CLLOcationCoordinate2D`. Instantiate and add those objects to your array.

```
@interface Coordinate : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end

@implementation Coordinate

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And then, because your `locationArray` is an array of `MKUserLocation` (which, itself, conforms to `MKAnnotation`), you can do:

```
NSMutableArray *path;

path = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in locationArray)
{
    // determine latitude and longitude

    [path addObject:[[Coordinate alloc] initWithCoordinate:annotation.coordinate]];
}
```

Or make an array of existing object type, such as `CLLocation` or `MKPinAnnotation` or whatever.

Or if this array is a path to be drawn on the map, you might want to avoid using your own array, and instead make a `MKPolyline`.

```
NSInteger pathLength = [locationArray count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D polylineCoordinates[pathLength];  // note, no malloc/free needed
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pathLength; i++)
{
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = locationArray[i];

    polylineCoordinates[i] = annotation.coordinate;
}
MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:polylineCoordinates count:pathLength]
[self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
```

It depends upon what the purpose of this is. But if you can use one of the previous constructs that avoids `malloc` and `free`, that's probably ideal. These techniques leverage Objective-C patterns which make it harder to leak, use an invalid pointer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You should certainly use `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` function 
with data from `MKUserLocation` or directly extract infos from `MKUserLocation`:

```
object.location.coordinate // it's a CLLocationCoordinate2D from your 'object' example
```

or

```
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(object.location.coordinate.latitude, object.location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Hope this help.